# Loop through Dictionary

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary with a Person and a Count value:

```
Dictionary<string, int> PersonDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

It has the following values:

```
Sally, 6
Beth, 5
Mary, 5
```

I want to alternate each person and decrement the value by 1 each time it goes through the loop.  I'm running into a real mind block on this one

What is the best way to get Sally and decrement by 1 and then go to Beth and decrement by 1 and then go to Mary and decrement by 1 and then go back to Sally...  So on and so forth.

Just add further clarification I want to loop through this and use the `owner.Key` value and pass that to another method.  So I need to be able to loop through this dictionary 1 at a time.

**Update:**

There are a few issues with my question.  One issue was the decrementing the dictionary while in a loop.  But my main question was how to iterate through each item [`Sally -> Beth -> Mary -> Sally`) until each persons value goes to 0  - That part is still the question at large.

Comment: I'm missing something here. Why do you have an if and else? Dictionaries have unique keys so there is no reason to check for dupes. Just `PersonDictionary[owner.Key] = owner.Value - 1;` should work fine.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify this: "Because it does it in order." What is the first "it" and the second "it" and what order are you referring to?

Comment: @aquinas performing `foreach (var owner in personDictionary) personDictionary[owner.Key] = owner.Value - 1; ` will yield an `InvalidOperationException`, as setting a value in a dictionary updates its internal version number hence invalidates the iterator.

Comment: @Aominè, fair point, but just adding `ToList` fixes that. It *seemed* like maybe there was something else going on, but maybe not. OP seems to have vanished so we may never know :)

Comment: Define: doesn't work.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - I really want to know how to iterate through each person in this dictionary and decrementing by 1 each time.  First Sally, then Beth, then Mary, then back to Sally.  My code snipped doesn't work because I'm missing how to go through each item by name until there are no more values left.

Comment: A while loop..?

Comment: @PatrickHofman - thanks that should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Linq it would be as follows:

```
personDictionary = personDictionary.ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value-1);
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that this will create a *copy* of the `Dictionary` which may or may not be an unwanted effect

Answer (score 5):

> The above DOESN'T work.

It doesn't work because it's not possible to modify the collection inside of `foreach` loop and iterate through it at the same time.

That's why when we loop through the dictionary and try to modify it - an exception is thrown.

In order to change *the same* values without creating a copy of them we could 
 iterate through a copy of `Keys` collection and use indexer:

```
foreach (var ownerKey in PersonDictionary.Keys.ToList())
{
    PersonDictionary[ownerKey]--;
}
```

This will copy the `Keys` but the `Dictionary` object itself and `Values` collection will remain the same. 
Or you could use `Aominè`s solution if making a copy of the entire dictionary is not an issue.